# How does "PowerAmp" make song quality better?

Tags: music-player

I am using Poweramp trial version.
I tried so many music player but can not find anything like poweramp.

I am curious how poweramp makes song quality better even using low quality headset.

Comment: Equalizer, it's that simple.

Comment: Android has also default equalizer.
Why does poweramp equalizer do great? [ technical answer would be appreciated ]

Comment: sorry IDK :P so I can only give a +1 to your question, good one

Comment: https://www.reddit.com/r/androiddev/comments/aohjqy/how_does_poweramp_make_song_quality_better/